# HTML/CSS - 3 columns that resize

Tags: html, css, layout, jquery-masonry

I am building a very simple page, powered by tumblr.

It has 3 columns of content in the main area. The content divs are all set to a width of 33% and floated left, most of the time this arranges itself as you would expect, but as you resize the window it seems to sometimes revert to 2 columns. Anyone know how to solve this?

The html is here: http://emilestest.tumblr.com

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the .item css width to: 32%. The browser probably miscalculates width sometimes so you probably have a extra pixel or two, so the float overlaps to next line.

Answer (score 0):

There is a Javascript action involved. Your `article` html elements gets the absolute position and some coordinates. Have a look over those scripts (or disable them, in order to use only CSS for positioning).

Comment: He is using masonry, that is a plugin used to position elements of different sizes in a grid.

Comment: Masonry was used by the theme i initially used as a base. I don't know enough about javascript/jQuery to fully understand why its causing a problem. I have noticed this page: iam.beyonce.com works exactly as i want and also uses masonry, i cant yet work out the difference.

Comment: There are tons of differences in how you use masonry and how the other site uses masonry. By using http://jsbeautifier.org/ you can get the http://static.tumblr.com/rseu6su/4vem9mru3/script.min.083112.js code and make it more readable. In there, check for instance the `masonryStart` function and compare it on how you start your own. And that's just one of the things that differs. Although, I do think that the issues of the columns are CSS related as mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

In your specific case, there are several solutions:

1. Place + size the `div`s with JavaScript and disable CSS layout
2. Use `display: table`
3. Use a `table` element

Disclaimer: For all those who cry out when they read `table`:

> Using divisions to simulate a table for the display of tabular data is as much a design flaw as using tables to control graphic and page layout.

Source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tableless_web_design#The_use_of_tables